# Impressão em Bematech

Tags: java, android

Pesquisei no Google mas não achei nenhum material que ajudasse.

Como posso enviar uma impressão de um aplicativo Android para uma impressora não fiscal Bematech que esteja conectada em um computador na mesma rede que o Mobile?

Comment: Você pode criar uma aplicação que rodará no no computador e receba o comando e dados para impressão, e o seu aplicativo se comunica com a aplicação.